# How to access the hardware serial number in iOS 8.1 (and above)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8.1

Since iOS 8.1, it seems no longer able to access the serial number by using IOKit:

```
CFTypeRef serialNumberAsCFString;
io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));

serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, CFSTR(kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);

NSString *sn = CFBridgingRelease(serialNumberAsCFString);
```

The `serialNumberAsCFString` at this point will be `0x0`, and thus the `sn` is null.

So how could the serial number be retrieved now? Or it is not possible anymore?

(I am totally aware that IOKit is a private framework, and its usage will cause the app to be rejected.)

Comment: Crash? What error? Try CFBridgingRelease.

Comment: @nicael thanks! CFBridgingRelease fixes the crash, but the string is still null.

Comment: So use just NSString *sn = CFBridgingRelease(serialNumberAsCFString) instead of stringWithFormat...

Comment: ah, found. thats IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty() which doesn't work anymore since iOS 8. will have to find another method.